# How to convert GTFS stop data to a spreadsheet?

Tags: convert, general-transit-feed-specification

I'm trying to make a timetable in a spreadsheet by converting the agency's provided GTFS data.

Unfortunately, I have been unable to find any tools for doing this. It seems as though many people use GTFS for maps, not scheduling.

Is there any tool that can make it a spreadsheet, or even HTML?

I looked at BlinkTag's tool but I can't use node-js so it doesn't meet my requirements.

Comment: There are required and optional files see https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference/#feed-files

Comment: On which city are you working on? Nowadays, there is GTFS data readily available on the government sites in either csv format or you need to extract it using API calls.

Comment: @HellblaZer I'm trying to convert GTFS data from New Jersey Transit.